# Could not resolved constructor at the ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I had added values inside the subjects table but could not retrieve the values out using ListView.

My code:

`DatabaseHelper.java`

```
 public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myexam.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.d("Database operations", "Database successfully created!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_USER = "CREATE TABLE " +
                user.TABLE_USER + "(" +
                user.USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," +
                user.USER_EMAIL + " VARCHAR NOT NULL," +
                user.USER_PASS + " VARCHAR NOT NULL," +
                user.USER_CPASS + " VARCHAR NOT NULL);";

        String CREATE_SUBJECT = "CREATE TABLE " +
                subject.TABLE_SUBJECT + "(" +
                subject.USER_ID + " INTEGER," +
                subject.SUBUSER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," +
                subject.SUBJECT_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                subject.SUBJECT_RESULTS + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                subject.SUBJECT_HOURS + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_USER);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_SUBJECT);
        Log.d("Database operations", "Table created!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + user.TABLE_USER);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + subject.TABLE_SUBJECT);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //insert User
    public boolean insertUser(String uid, String email, String pass, String cpass) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(user.USER_ID, uid);
        cv.put(user.USER_EMAIL, email);
        cv.put(user.USER_PASS, pass);
        cv.put(user.USER_CPASS, cpass);
        long user_id =  db.insert(user.TABLE_USER, null, cv);

        if (user_id == -1){
            return false;
        }else
            return true;
    }

    //get User
    public Cursor getUser(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT "+ user.USER_ID + ", " + user.USER_PASS + " FROM " + user.TABLE_USER;

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        return c;
    }

    //insert Subjects
    public boolean insertSubjects(String uid, String sname, String sresults, String shours) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(subject.SUBUSER_ID, uid);
        cv.put(subject.SUBJECT_NAME, sname);
        cv.put(subject.SUBJECT_RESULTS, sresults);
        cv.put(subject.SUBJECT_HOURS, shours);
        long sub_id =  db.insert(subject.TABLE_SUBJECT, null, cv);

        if (sub_id == -1){
            return false;
        }else
            return true;
    }

    public Cursor getSubjects(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT "+ subject.SUBUSER_ID +
                            ", " + subject.SUBJECT_NAME +
                            ", " + subject.SUBJECT_RESULTS +
                            ", " + subject.SUBJECT_HOURS +
                            " FROM " + subject.TABLE_SUBJECT +
                            " WHERE " + subject.SUBUSER_ID +
                            " = " + subject.USER_ID;

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        return c;
    }
}
```

subject.java

```
public class subject {
    public static final String SUBUSER_ID = "etUID";
    public static final String USER_ID = user.USER_ID;
    public static final String SUBJECT_NAME = "etSubjects";
    public static final String SUBJECT_RESULTS = "etResults";
    public static final String SUBJECT_HOURS = "etHours";
    public static final String TABLE_SUBJECT = "subjects";
}
```

`user.java`

```
 public class user {
    public static final String USER_ID = "etID";
    public static final String USER_EMAIL = "etEmail";
    public static final String USER_PASS = "etPassword";
    public static final String USER_CPASS = "etCPassword";
    public static final String TABLE_USER = "user";
}
```

`addSubject.java`

```
public class addSubjects extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText etUID, etSubjects, etResults, etHours;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_subjects);

        etUID = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUID);
        etSubjects = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etSubjects);
        etResults = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etResults);
        etHours = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etHours);

        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_add_subjects, menu);
        return true;
    }

   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

       if(id == android.R.id.home){
           Intent i = new Intent(this, subjects.class);
           startActivity(i);
           finish();
       }

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
       if (id == R.id.action_home) {
           Intent i = new Intent(this, Menus.class);
           startActivity(i);
           finish();
       }
       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void SaveInfo(View view){
        String userid = etUID.getText().toString();
        String subjects = etSubjects.getText().toString();
        String results = etResults.getText().toString();
        String hours = etHours.getText().toString();

        if(userid.equals("") || subjects.equals("") || results.equals("") || hours.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(addSubjects.this, "Please key in all the information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if((!results.equals("A")) && (!results.equals("B")) && (!results.equals("C")) && (!results.equals("D")) && (!results.equals("F"))){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please key in valid results!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if((!hours.equals("One")) && (!hours.equals("Two")) && (!hours.equals("Three")) && (!hours.equals("Four"))){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please key in valid hours!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            boolean isInserted = databaseHelper.insertSubjects(userid, subjects, results, hours);
            if(isInserted = true){
                Toast.makeText(addSubjects.this, "Added Successfully!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(this, subjects.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(addSubjects.this, "Unsuccessfully added!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`subject.java` (`ListView`)

```
package com.smartexamorganizer.subjects;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.smartexamorganizer.ListData.ListDataAdapter;
import com.smartexamorganizer.ListData.SubjectProvider;
import com.smartexamorganizer.R;
import com.smartexamorganizer.activity.Menus;
import com.smartexamorganizer.database.DatabaseHelper;

public class subjects extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lvSubjects;

    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    Cursor cursor;
    ListDataAdapter listDataAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_subjects);

        lvSubjects = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvSubjects);

        listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.display_subjects_row);
        lvSubjects.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);

        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = databaseHelper.getSubjects();

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String sub_name, sub_results, sub_hours;
                sub_name = cursor.getString(0);
                sub_results = cursor.getString(1);
                sub_hours = cursor.getString(2);

                SubjectProvider subjectProvider = new SubjectProvider(sub_name, sub_results, sub_hours);
                listDataAdapter.add(subjectProvider); //pass each row of data

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_subjects, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_add) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, addSubjects.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }

        if (id == R.id.action_home) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Menus.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

`ListDataAdapter.java`

```
package com.smartexamorganizer.ListData;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.smartexamorganizer.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Acer on 12/18/2015.
 */
public class ListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    List list = new ArrayList();
    public ListDataAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    static class LayoutHandler{
        TextView SUB_NAME, SUB_RESULTS, SUB_HOURS;
    }
    @Override
    public void add(Object object) {
        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
        if(row == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.display_subjects_row, parent, false);
            layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
            layoutHandler.SUB_NAME = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvSub_Name);
            layoutHandler.SUB_RESULTS = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvSub_Results);
            layoutHandler.SUB_HOURS = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvSub_Hours);
            row.setTag(layoutHandler);
        }
        else{
            layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler)row.getTag();
        }
        SubjectProvider subjectProvider = (SubjectProvider) this.getItem(position);
        layoutHandler.SUB_NAME.setText(subjectProvider.getSub_name());
        layoutHandler.SUB_RESULTS.setText(subjectProvider.getSub_results());
        layoutHandler.SUB_HOURS.setText(subjectProvider.getSub_hours());

        return row;
    }
}
```

`SubjectProvider.java`

```
public class SubjectProvider {
    private String sub_name;
    private String sub_results;
    private String sub_hours;

    public SubjectProvider(String sub_name, String sub_results, String sub_hours){
        this.sub_name = sub_name;
        this.sub_results = sub_results;
        this.sub_hours = sub_hours;
    }

    public String getSub_hours() {
        return sub_hours;
    }

    public void setSub_hours(String sub_hours) {
        this.sub_hours = sub_hours;
    }

    public String getSub_name() {
        return sub_name;
    }

    public void setSub_name(String sub_name) {
        this.sub_name = sub_name;
    }

    public String getSub_results() {
        return sub_results;
    }

    public void setSub_results(String sub_results) {
        this.sub_results = sub_results;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Error:(40, 45) error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(subjects,int,ArrayList<SubjectProvider>)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; ArrayList<SubjectProvider> cannot be converted to int)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,String[]) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; ArrayList<SubjectProvider> cannot be converted to String[])
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,List<String>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; ArrayList<SubjectProvider> cannot be converted to List<String>)
```

Comment: In your oncreate method you misspelled varchar.

Comment: @Nyxar oops!!! thanks btw :D

Comment: Did you insert the user in the database with the good userId?

Comment: @Dimitri
i added like 1111
thn the second want is 2222

i just tried to use different id which is simple first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
// getSubjects() will now return a List of SubjectProviders
// as you can see below
public ArrayList<SubjectProvider> getSubjects(){ 
    // obtain the database
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    // create the query that should return name results and hours
    // for each subject that has the subuser_id equal to the user_id
    String selectQuery = "SELECT " + subject.SUBJECT_NAME +
                        ", " + subject.SUBJECT_RESULTS +
                        ", " + subject.SUBJECT_HOURS +
                        " FROM " + subject.TABLE_SUBJECT +
                        " WHERE " + subject.SUBUSER_ID +
                        " = " + subject.USER_ID;

    // create the arraylist in which we will late store all the subjectproviders
    // this arraylist will be returned so you can use it in your subjects class
    ArrayList<SubjectProvider> subjectList = new  ArrayList<SubjectProvider>()
    // execute the select-query
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // if the cursor is not empty aka some at least one row was found
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        // loop through all the results
        do {
            System.out.println("Results were found!");
            // get the values from the cursor
            String sub_name, sub_results, sub_hours;
            sub_name = cursor.getString(0);
            sub_results = cursor.getString(1);
            sub_hours = cursor.getString(2);

            // create a new subjectprovider Object to store the values in it
            SubjectProvider subjectProvider = new SubjectProvider(sub_name, sub_results, sub_hours);

            System.out.println("Subject: "+sub_name+" got" +sub_results+" in "+sub_hours);
            // add it to the arraylist
            subjectList.add(subjectProvider);
        // stop if there are no more results
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    // return the list to your subjects class
    return subjectList;
}
```

and in subjects:

```
    // create a new arraylist, that will contain the values from your
    // getsubjects method

     ArrayList<SubjectProvider> my_array_list = (ArrayList<SubjectProvider>) databaseHelper.getSubjects();
    // create an adapter so you can add the values from the arraylist to your listview
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
             subjects.this, 
             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
             my_array_list);

     // set the previously created adapter as an adapter for your listview
     lvSubjects.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Insert method:

```
//insert Subjects
public boolean insertSubjects(Integer id, Integer uid, String sname, String sresults, String shours) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(user.USER_ID, id);
    cv.put(subject.SUBUSER_ID, uid);
    cv.put(subject.SUBJECT_NAME, sname);
    cv.put(subject.SUBJECT_RESULTS, sresults);
    cv.put(subject.SUBJECT_HOURS, shours);
    long sub_id =  db.insert(subject.TABLE_SUBJECT, null, cv);

    if (sub_id == -1){
        return false;
    }else
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: i had made the changes! thanks!
now trying to solve another problems with the same code ><

the data did not displayed out after inserting the subject~

Comment: try recreating the database. I think you still managed to create the subjects table, although the users one gave the error, and now you try to insert data that is already there. That is why I posted the code with another database name, it should work. do not forget to delete the other one.

Comment: or drop the subjects table, and try again to insert the values, should also work

Comment: subjects data is inserted but cant view in the listView... do i need to post out my listView?

Comment: oh, so you do not get the above error. ok, well, yeah, post how you try to insert the values

Comment: I had posted the addSubjects.java and subject.java (ListView) above~~

Comment: ok, does the cursor manage to get the values? Try printing out sub_name, sub_results and sub_hours

Comment: nope~There's nothing out after inserting everything~
and im not sure whether is the getSubject in DatabaseHelper.java there wrong or I miss some coding ><

and i got the error of unique constraint when adding the values

Comment: getSubjects() is returning alot more values than you actualy need, including SUBUSER_ID

Comment: just tpo make sure you want all subjects that have the SUB_USER_ID equal to the USER_ID, right? like: (1, Mary,..., 1)

Comment: but there's is nothing listing out after inserting the values needed~~

if i din include the SUBUSER_ID, i cant retrieve the values based on the user_id~ is there any solutions to solve?

Comment: ya~
something like
id = 1111

all the 1111 id subjects will list out

Comment: ok, I  editited your method, but I'm not quite sure, that it is doing what you want it to do. can you post an example of an INSERT, that should be listed?

Comment: User login:
ID: 1111
PWD: 1111aaaa!


Adding subject:
ID Number: 1111
Subject's Name: abcd
Subject's Resutls: C
Hours of study: Two

Things that should list out:
Name, Results and hours

Comment: does the getSubjects method return anything? there is no connection between the two tables you have.

Comment: so USER_ID and SUBUSER_ID are both 1111 in subjects table in the database?

Comment: As the codes showed above, it return Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null)

USER_ID in user database
SUBUSER_ID in subject database

Comment: Did you try printing anything out?

Comment: What do you mean actual values??

I had entered two different values in subjects table
but only one retrieve out

Comment: does it or does it not print anything?

Comment: you know what? just update your question, with the current code including insert statement(the sql one, not your 'example') and the current problem

Comment: I had updated latest code~ All the SQLite codes in the databaseHelper.java~
hope you can see it

Comment: ok, just copy paste this instead of your method, and tell me if it works

Comment: there's is an error at the subject.java (ListView)

for the cursor = databaseHelper.getSubjects();

Comment: what error. srsly, if you want help you need to be alot more explicit

Comment: I had tried this solution before~
but im not understand about the ArrayList<Name>(): with the cursor

any difference?

Comment: no, but removing USER_ID does and using ArrayAdapter also

Comment: in databaseHelper 
subjectList.add(subject)

and 
i need to create new class for the ArrayList<SubjectProvider> list_name?

cause i do not have the list_name since im just retrieve it from database

Comment: no! here I edited the code. it was just a typo. you are not a programmer, are you?

Comment: where did I write list_name? there is no list_name

Comment: just do not create another class

Comment: im mean this want your_array_list ><

im just start learning this~sorry for cumbersome~~~the first want I solved~ 
left the ArrayList<SubjectProvider> your_array_list~

im not very understand about this~ why should we use this instead of using the ListArrayAdapter?

Comment: databaseHelper.getSubjects(); returns an Object of type ArrayList<SubjectProvider>, so you can just write it like that

Comment: please wait awhile~ im trying to digest~ but i got the error at the subjects.java there for the ArrayList<SubjectProvider> your_array_list~
so, im trying to understand the codes first~ thn i try to solve the problems~ thanks

Comment: alright~~ 
it still cant work cause the error of the ArrayList in subjects.java shows "cannot resolved constructor"

Comment: did you import arrayList?

Comment: where did constructor need to be create?
subject?
arrayAdapter?

im having ListDataAdapter... does it different with arrayAdapter?

ya

Comment: it does not, you actually do have it

Comment: then where does i need to create constructor since everything is ok ?

im still not understand ><

Comment: copy the error, the whole error and edit it in the question, not as a comment

Comment: i think i solved it too. it's because of the context

Comment: i eddited it with the solution. see, it is alot easier to find a solution if you know the problem(error). still not working?

Comment: i thinks there is sth wrong with the ID there~ cause i got the errors of UNIQUE constraint failed: subjects.etUID

Comment: hahaha~~~thanks for helping!!!

sorry for any cumbersome!!! 
will try to solve and post the actual answer !!!

Comment: your problem is that you try to insert the same value more than once. your insert is incorrect!

Comment: you try to insert Strings instead of integeres, you completely ignored user_id, although it is not a foreign key to the other table, and probably many more other things....

Answer (score 1):

`VARCHAR` not `VARCAHR`:
Change:

```
user.USER_EMAIL + " VARCAHR NOT NULL," +
user.USER_PASS + " VARCAHR NOT NULL," +
user.USER_CPASS + " VARCAHR NOT NULL);";
```

to

```
 user.USER_EMAIL + " VARCHAR NOT NULL," +
 user.USER_PASS + " VARCHAR NOT NULL," +
 user.USER_CPASS + " VARCHAR NOT NULL);";
```

and increase the `database version` from 1 to 2:

```
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
```

Comment: any difference with the database version?

Comment: to recreate the database with it's table it is necessary to increase the version. see my edit

Comment: thanks! i had changed!

anyway, do you know how to list out all the data based on the user_id?
did i done wrong at the getSubjects in DatabaseHelper?

I only can insert one value and retrieve it one without any error but when i insert another value it automatically close my app ><

Comment: E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1555) abort at 14 in [INSERT INTO subjects(etResults,etHours,etUID,etSubjects) VALUES (?,?,?,?)]: UNIQUE constraint failed: subjects.etUID
12-18 21:28:13.021  22330-22330/com.smartexamorganizer E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting etResults=C etHours=One etUID=1111 etSubjects=English
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: subjects.etUID (code 1555)

Comment: the uuid already exists after you added it the first time. the second one must fail because uuid was not changed on android side and it is a primary field

Comment: noted!! but then how do i called the another data if i din key in the uuid?

Comment: i had posted out my addSubject.java~
it's there any wrong with the code since I could not used the same uuid~